# how to hide bootstrap-vue table header row

Tags: vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

`bootstrap-vue` will by default create a header row for my data.
Is there any way to hide the header row for a `<b-table>` so only data items will be rendered?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From the documentation [here](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table/#component-reference), there is an option to set the class for the header (i.e the generated `<thead>`) with `thead-class` set to the `<b-table>` element, or to the header row (i.e the `<tr>` element under the `<thead>`) with `thead-tr-class` set to the `<b-table>`.
Only note that is the `<style>` is scoped this will not work.
Here is a simple component based on this idea.

```html
<template>
  <b-table :items="items" thead-class="hidden_header"/>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'my-table',
  props: {
    items: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    }
  }
}
</script>

<!-- If we add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only 
     the hide of the header will not work! -->
<style scoped>
    <!-- put scoped CSS here -->
</style>
<style>
.hidden_header {
  display: none;
}
</style>
```

Comment: May I add that instead of using a custom class `.hidden_header`, you could more easily use the Bootstrap default `d-none`, which will hide it.

Comment: thx the scoped hint helped me a lot. now i would like to ask why that is that scoped prevents it? if none other parent component is setting some attribute, and it is only handled in that component why doesn't the scoped work? thanks

Answer (score 20):

you could simply use "bootstrap magic" and add `thead-class="d-none"` to hide the header row:

```html
<template>
  <b-table :items="items" thead-class="d-none" />
</template>
```

Comment: That is much simpler

Answer (score 6):

In your fields object add thStyle each column.

```
fields: [{
  key: 'key_here',
  label: 'Column Name',
  thStyle: {
     display: 'none'
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like there is anything in docs to hide the row completely, but you can use CSS to hide it:

```
table > thead {
    display:none !important;
}
```

The !important flag is to override the default settings.

Comment: Thanks! yet I was looking for a more "vueish" solution

Comment: This is the best solution for my case. Thanks!